# Why doesn't this mysql query successfully insert to my db?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the following script to send submitted data to my database. It seems I'm failing, and get an error from mysqli_error telling me that my sql syntax is wrong. Yet I'm following the syntax as it's stated in my book.

If Get['save'] is set, that means the form was submitted. I tried adding backticks around my column names as suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow but to no avail.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[(`person`, `age`)] VALUES ({$person, $age})' at line 1"
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\contacthmw3\index.php on line 33
>
> ```
> Call Stack  
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location  
> 1 0.0024  148104  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0  
> 2 0.0163  157640  mysqli_fetch_array ( )  ..\index.php:33
> ```

```
   <?php
    include_once 'magicquotes.php';
    include_once 'db.inc.php'; // connects, sets chars, selects db
    include_once 'form.php'; // just saves form to $form

    $sqlselect = 'SELECT person, age FROM people;
      SELECT email, phone FROM contacts;';
    if (!isset($_GET['save'])) {
        echo $form;
    } else {
        $person = $_GET['person'];
        $age = $_GET['age'];
        $email = $_GET['email'];
        $phone = $_GET['phone'];
        $sqlsave = 'INSERT INTO people (`person`, `age`) VALUES ($person, $age);';
        $savedtodb = mysqli_query($link, $sqlsave);
        if (!$savedtodb)
        {echo 'Failed to save to db' . mysqli_error($link);}
        // send form submission to db with sanitized data
    }

    $contacts = mysqli_query($link, $sqlselect); //retrieve data into $contacts array
    if (!$contacts) {
        echo 'Failed to get contacts from db.' . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($contacts)) {
        $showme[] = array('person' => $row['person'], 'age' => $row['age']);


        foreach ($showme as $indiv => $age) {
            echo $indiv . $age;
        }
    }
    ?>


    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['save'])):
    ?>
        <p>Last details entered into the table:</p>
        <table border="1">
            <tr> <th>Person</th><th>Age</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
            <tr>

                <td> <?php echo $_GET['person']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $_GET['age']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $_GET['email']; ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo $_GET['phone']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: That's not the query that the book told you to write.

Comment: Use [bind variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of inserting unescaped and unquoted input into the query.

Comment: you didn't initialize $link

Comment: Variables in strings enclosed in single quotes do not get evaluated. Use double quotes to produce or, even better, prepared statements.

Comment: I didn't say it's the query they told me to write, I said it's following the syntax. Can you elaborate what you observed as being the problem, please, Lightness?
@Sebas I did, that's what the db.inc.php does. I should have specified. 
Niko it may be I'm too close to my own code, but I don't see any vars in single quotes. Can you specify which, please?

Comment: Niko - thanks - that solved it. I needed to wrap the whole INSERT statement in double quotes and the individual column values in single quotes. Can someone with rep on SO thumb him up please?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to execute multiple queries using [mysqli_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) rather than with [mysqli_multi_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php); and you should probably be running a single query using a join to get the results you want

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that function - thanks for the insightful tip. Also didn't know about joins (I'm a newb, please bear with me). Really appreciate the help Mark1

Comment: Update: I ran the query through the SQL Buddy program, with dummy values instead of my parameters. Turned out that I was getting an 'unrecognized column ...' error. Fixed that, fixed the syntax of the SQL statement (e.g. got rid of backticks which were not helping) and then wrapped the whole INSERT statement in double quotes, as Niko suggested. Hattip to this thread for showing me good syntax: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/118055/php-variable-in-mysql-query#

Comment: That said, your point re: mysqli_multi_query allowed me to get both queries entered in one go, which was the goal.

Comment: I also hadn't designed my tables with foreign keys hence could not use joins.

Comment: You can still use joins even without foreign keys... foreign keys are used for managing constraints and cascade actions